# Value compare between columns of a Pandas Dataframe and Assign it to another column called results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[Data Farme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0911.jpg)

As we see in the Picture of my dataframe,

I have a data Frame with Column names "Actual Touches" and "Expected Touches"

Now I want to Value compare between the columns '**Actual Touches**' and '**Expected Touches**', taking base as 'Expected Touches' and assign the results to a third column named 'Results' (like if value in 'Actual Touches'== 'Expected Touches', then in the results column it should represent pass else fail.)

Thanks for your time,

Comment: [Please not upload images of code or data on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thanks for the info, I'm Kind of new to SO and its just my second question.

Comment: bdw i think you can try `df['result']=np.where(df['Acutal Touches'].eq(df['Expected Touches']),'pass','fail')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.!

Answer (score 0):

This will create a column called `value` in your dataframe stating whether or not value in `Actual Touches` and `Expected Touches` are equal.

```py
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x : True if x['Actual Touches'] == x['Expected Touches'] else False, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too :)

Comment: No problem ! :)